# Camel Split list<MyObject> in header

Tags: java, split, apache-camel

Can I split list of my object?
Like this [Camel- Split List<MyObj> and process each java object - XML Config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18365209/camel-split-listmyobj-and-process-each-java-object-xml-config)
but, for header.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
from("direct:start")
    .split(simple("header.myHeader"))
    .log("Split: ${body}");
```

Tested with:

```
final ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", "World!", "myHeader", Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Log:

```
INFO  Split: a
INFO  Split: b
INFO  Split: c
```

Comment: For further reference, please enclose the simple string in curly brackets: `${header.myHeader}`